Issue Referencing Secret Variable in Azure Dev Ops
My Current set up uses Azure Key Vault.
I have set up a Variable group in my Azure DevOPs which is linked to the Variable group.  I have also give my pipeline permission to access the Variable group.  However I'm getting an issue trying to get the varable and use it in an Inline Script in the Yaml.
How do I escape the Variable so that it will allow the secret to have Special Characters in it and access it in Inline PS?
trigger:
- #none

pool:
  name: 'DeployAgentPool' # name of the self-hosted agent pool
variables:
  group: Onyx-Production-Variable-Group

------   other code -------
- stage: BackupDatabase
  displayName: 'Backup SQL Database (Front End)'
  jobs:
  - job: BackupDatabaseJob
    displayName: 'Backup SQL Database(Front End)'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
 steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Backup SQL Database (Front End)'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          Write-Output "Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage"
          
          if ($env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK -ne $null) {
            Write-Output "Key Vault secret successfully retrieved."

            $backupFileName = "SQLBK$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss).bacpac"
            $password = $(SqlAdmin2)

          $stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey = $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK 

            Write-Output "Password length: $($password.Length)"  
            Write-Output "Storage account key length: $($stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey.Length)"     

            az sql db export --admin-password $password `
                            --admin-user "sqladmin" `
                            --storage-key '$stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey' ` <<<---Does Not WORK
                            --storage-key-type "StorageAccessKey" `
                            --storage-uri "https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/$backupFileName" `
                            --name "sqldb-frontend-prod" `
                            --resource-group "$(ResourceGroup)" `
                            --server "sql-onyx-prod"

            Write-Output "Database backup completed successfully!"
          } else {
            Write-Output "Key Vault secret not retrieved. Check variable group and pipeline linkage."
          }
      env:
        STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK: $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk)}

Here is the Log:
2024-11-26T18:27:18.2894352Z Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage
2024-11-26T18:27:18.2917555Z Key Vault secret successfully retrieved.
2024-11-26T18:27:18.2940017Z Password length: 16
2024-11-26T18:27:18.2941703Z Storage account key length: 27
2024-11-26T18:27:23.2179512Z ERROR: (InvalidImportExportStorageKeyFormat) The ImportExport operation failed because of invalid storage key format.
2024-11-26T18:27:23.2180164Z Code: InvalidImportExportStorageKeyFormat
2024-11-26T18:27:23.2180652Z Message: The ImportExport operation failed because of invalid storage key format.

Additional Attempts
Everything else kept same.
Here is the value stored in  Keyvault: (Its Skewed on purpose)

Xm5MDLVQ0+EvJEEr+GIfqfhYyA5zsAuk3f3RSTyzh1WfLyRmQZqDG+vmhwGlI45UvxAFUWSNM+AStt5gNAQ==

If I change to : --storage-key $stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey:
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5750465Z Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5771106Z Key Vault secret successfully retrieved.
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5859694Z Password length: 16
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5860520Z Storage account key length: 27
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5863688Z --storage-key-type was unexpected at this time.
2024-11-27T12:44:29.5877003Z D:\a\1\s>  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli sql db export --admin-password *** --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241127124429.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod

IF I change to : --storage-key "$stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey":
2024-11-27T12:46:31.2358276Z Key Vault secret successfully retrieved.
2024-11-27T12:46:31.2372104Z Password length: 16
2024-11-27T12:46:31.2384041Z Storage account key length: 27
2024-11-27T12:46:31.2505543Z --storage-key-type was unexpected at this time.
2024-11-27T12:46:31.2507143Z D:\a\1\s>  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli sql db export --admin-password *** --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241127124631.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod

If I change to:   --storage-key $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK:
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3582802Z Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3609111Z Key Vault secret successfully retrieved.
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3728853Z Password length: 16
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3731111Z Storage account key length: 27
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3734574Z --storage-key-type was unexpected at this time.
2024-11-27T12:51:09.3735930Z D:\a\1\s>  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli sql db export --admin-password *** --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241127125109.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod

EDIT 2 USING KEYVAULT TASK
I've officially switched to using the KeyVault Task. Which works and is acceptable in this case.  However there is still the issue with the special characters not being escaped correctly..  (also I really hate this PW)..    Here is the code that is being run. and the following log.   I'm doing a comparison in clear text for testing purposes on what the pw is and should be.  It passes that test, but, when it is used in the AZ Cmd it gets hung up on the special characters.
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Backup Front End SQL Database to Frontend Blob'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      Write-Output "Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage"
          if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK)) {
          Write-Output "The environment variable STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK is either null or empty."
            } else {
                    Write-Output "The environment variable STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK has a value: $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK"
          }
          if ($env:SQLADMINPW -ne $null) {
          Write-Output "SQL ADMIN secret successfully retrieved."
          }

          if ($env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK -ne $null) {
          Write-Output "Storage Key  secret successfully retrieved."

          $backupFileName = "SQLBK$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss).bacpac"

          #$password = $(SqlAdmin2)
          #$password = $($env:SQLADMINPW)

          $password = $env:SQLADMINPW
          
          # Perform the comparison
          if ($password -eq 'me*()oPR3!swet') {
             Write-Output "Password matches expected value."
          } else {
              Write-Output "Password does not match the expected value."
          } 
         

         
          Write-Output "Password length: $($password.Length)"  
  
          Write-Output "Executing command: az sql db export --admin-password [REDACTED] --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key "$($stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey)" --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/$backupFileName --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) --server sql-onyx-prod"
          

          az sql db export `
              --admin-password $password  `
              --admin-user "sqladmin" `
              --storage-key $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK `
              --storage-key-type "StorageAccessKey" `
              --storage-uri "https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/$backupFileName" `
              --name "sqldb-frontend-prod" `
              --resource-group "$(ResourceGroup)" `
              --server "sql-onyx-prod" `

          Write-Output "Database backup completed successfully!"
      } else {
          Write-Output "Key Vault secret not retrieved. Check variable group and pipeline linkage."
      }                           
  env:                          
    STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK: $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) #works
    SQLADMINPW: $(SqlAdminPassword)   #actual value: me*()oPR3!swet

   

Logs fail with Unexpected value due to special characters.
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9194778Z Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9295801Z The environment variable STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK has a value: ***
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9309317Z SQL ADMIN secret successfully retrieved.
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9313711Z Storage Key  secret successfully retrieved.
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9364242Z Password matches expected value.
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9395776Z Password length: 14
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9399725Z Storage account key length: 88
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9402513Z Executing command: az sql db export --admin-password [REDACTED] --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key 
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9404924Z ***
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9408024Z  --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://stonyxdbasebakprod.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241204131557.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod
2024-12-04T13:15:57.9410176Z Debug Password (unmasked): ***
2024-12-04T13:15:58.0099423Z oPR3!swet was unexpected at this time.

More attempts:
az sql db export --admin-password $env:SQLADMINPW`
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7271654Z The environment variable STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK has a value: ***
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7286251Z SQL ADMIN secret successfully retrieved.
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7291313Z Storage Key  secret successfully retrieved.
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7341046Z Password matches expected value.
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7372240Z Password length: 14
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7391037Z Executing command: az sql db export --admin-password [REDACTED] --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key 
2024-12-04T15:09:26.7392021Z  --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://stonyxdbasebakprod.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241204150926.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod
2024-12-04T15:09:26.8114675Z oPR3!swet was unexpected at this time.

az sql db export --admin-password "$password"`

Identical result to above.

check variables are enclosed in double quotes ", particularly when passed to commands and also use single quotes ' in YAML where necessary to prevent the pipeline from interpreting special characters.

Any luck with your issue?

@Rui Jarimba,  I have given up on the Variable group completely.   Ended up using a AzureKeyVault@2 task..   to retrieve the variables.  And it works as expected for the storage key.   Now I'm trying to deal with special characters on the   However I am encountering issues with special characters.   { $password } and its not going great.

Setting environment variables at the task level using env should solve the problem of characters escaping/special characters.
Run the pipeline in diagnostics mode and take a good look at the logs of the task to ensure pipeline variables are being processed/expanded correctly - if you see something like $(xxxxxx) in the logs then there's something wrong.

@RuiJarimba  The Password is now not working correctly in the az sql command.   I'm running logs and outputing the logs  with the correct Length, but then the log thows an unexpected character error.    Do you have a slimed down example of passing Password into inline script. with special characters in it?     even az sql db export --admin-password $env:SQLADMINPW --admin-user "sqladmin" throws error when it encounters the Secret Character.   Example  if Pw: pas*()woord   error would be : woord was unexpected at this time.

I honestly can't reproduce your issue, everything works as expected when using env.  Are you using Microsoft or self-hosted build agents? Windows or Linux? Try using scriptType: pscore.

The issue in this situation is that the parameter needs to be wrapped in quotes inside the variable.
Process to solve this issue.

Verify the variables are coming in from either Pipeline, KeyVault, etc. (since you can't see them, because they are secrets, you can do a comparison eq with the Actual value you paste in.

Try the {az sql db export} cmd with the actual values.

Replicate the values in the paramaters. Im my case I had to enclose the Pwd in quotes inside the variable. Then pass that to the cmd.
stage: BackupFrontEndDatabase
displayName: 'Backup  Database (Front End) Stage'
jobs:
job: BackupDatabaseJob
displayName: 'Backup  Database(Front End) Job'
    steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      displayName: 'Retrieve Key Vault Secrets for StorageAccountKey'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        KeyVaultName: 'kv-onyx-$(Environment)'
        SecretsFilter: '*'    #Retrieve all secrets. you could specify exactly which ones. 

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Backup Front End SQL Database to Frontend Blob'

      inputs:

        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          Write-Output "Debug: Checking Key Vault variable linkage"

          if ($env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK -ne $null) {
              Write-Output "Storage Key secret successfully retrieved."

              $backupFileName = "SQLBK$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss).bacpac"

              # Define Storage Account and Container
              $storageAccountName = "s$(Environment)"
              $containerName = "dbasebk"



              $password = "`"$env:SQLADMINPW`""          #  THIS IS THE KEY.  

              # Execute the SQL export command
              az sql db export `
                  --admin-password $password `
                  --admin-user "sqladmin" `
                  --storage-key $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK `
                  --storage-key-type "StorageAccessKey" `
                  --storage-uri "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$backupFileName" `
                  --name "sqldb-frontend-$(Environment)" `
                  --resource-group "$(ResourceGroup)" `
                  --server "sql-onyx-$(Environment)" 

              Write-Output "Database backup completed successfully!"
          } else {
              Write-Output "Key Vault secret not retrieved. Check variable group and pipeline linkage."
          }
      env: 
        STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK: $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk)
        SQLADMINPW: $(SqlAdminPassword)           #   <<<<<<    actual value: me*()oPR3!swet




When variables are used from Variable Groups, it is not easy to use template expressions or even macro expressions.
You can try the bellow:

Define a job variable and escape characters \ and "
Use the variable in your task

-job:MyJob
 variables:
    myEscapedSecret: $[replace(replace(variables['STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK'], '\', '\\'), '"', '\"')]

 steps:
   -task: xxxxxx
    inlineScript: |
     az xxxx  --storage-key "$(myEscapedSecret)"



How do I escape the variable so that it will allow the secret to have special characters in it?

Declaring environment variables using env: is probably the best way to deal with pipeline variables containing special characters, as you're already doing.
Assuming that $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) contains the right value, there's no need to escape special characters.
trigger:
- #none

pool:
  name: 'DeployAgentPool' # name of the self-hosted agent pool
variables:
  group: Onyx-Production-Variable-Group   #< Variable Group here. 

stages:
- stage: BackupDatabase
  displayName: 'Backup SQL Database (Front End)'
  jobs:
  - job: BackupDatabaseJob
    displayName: 'Backup SQL Database(Front End)'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Backup SQL Database (Front End)'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          # ...
      env:
        STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK: $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk)

Your problem is probably caused by the usage of single-quoted strings.
Expressions in single-quoted strings aren't evaluated. They're interpreted as string literals.
Instead of:
az sql db export ... --storage-key '$stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey' ...

Try one of the following:
az sql db export ... --storage-key $stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey ...
az sql db export ... --storage-key "$stonyxdbasebakStorageAccountKey" ...
az sql db export ... --storage-key $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK ...


EDIT 1
Analysing your logs, it seems that the initial issue is now solved but one of the pipeline variables is not being resolved properly:

... --admin-password *** --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) ...

Double-check the following:

Ensure both the variable and the variable group containing it are properly spelled, i.e. there are no typos
Ensure the variable group has the right scope


EDIT 2
Consider the following variable group containing a variable with value p\tas*()w/o"o'r\nd:

Running the following pipeline using a Linux self-hosted agent, everything works as expected:
pool: Default

trigger: none

variables:
  - group: MyVariableGroup

  # Testing with local variables
  
  # - name: password
  #   value: 'pas*()wo"ord'

  # - name: password
  #   value: "pas*()wo'ord"

jobs:
  - job: DisplayPassword
    displayName: 'Display password'
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    steps:
      - checkout: none

      - pwsh: |
          Write-Host $Env:SQLADMINPW
          Write-Host "${Env:SQLADMINPW}"

          $myPassword = $Env:SQLADMINPW

          Write-Host $myPassword
          Write-Host "$($mypassword)"
        displayName: 'Display password'
        env:
          SQLADMINPW: $(password)

      - script: |
          echo $SQLADMINPW > "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/artifact.txt"

          echo "Password: $SQLADMINPW"
        displayName: 'Display password'
        env:
          SQLADMINPW: $(password)
      
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish  password as Pipeline Artifact'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifact: 'artifact'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'

Output of the pwsh task:


no luck on any of those attempts. I updated the Orginal post to show the results.

@JoeRicklefs I believe the issue with the storage key is now solved. If you look carefully at your logs, you no longer see the (InvalidImportExportStorageKeyFormat) The ImportExport operation failed because of invalid storage key format error. Now you have a different issue.

@JoeRicklefs are you using a shared or a storage access key? What happens if you try with --storage-key-type SharedAccessKey? And which version of the Azure CLI are you using?

StorageAccount Access key.   If I just paste it, in clear text it works perfect.

azure CLI  2.67.0

I get that it has a different error, but I beleive that its still related to how the actual value is being interpereted.

@JoeRicklefs you're retrieving the password from an Azure Keyvault, right? Double-check if the value of the secret in the keyvault is correct. Also, check if the command is somehow malformed - maybe try testing the az sql db ... command in a single line? BTW I'd recommend using an environment variable instead of using $(SqlAdmin2) directly in the script, just like you did for the key.

@JoeRicklefs the last line of your logs in the "Aditional Attempts" part of your question is showing a variable that was not expanded: ... sql db export ... --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) ... - how and where are you getting or setting pipeline variable $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk)? You need to ensure this variable is available in the job where your task is running?

I'm not seeing where you speaking about in regards to the not expanded variable.

@Ruijarimaba I only modified the Lines suggested above. in your comment when generating the logs

@JoeRicklefs not sure if I understand your comment. I see the string $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) in the last line of the logs you added in the "Addtional Attemps" part - this means that the pipeline variable is NOT available in your task. You need to clarify where that variable is defined or retrieved (same job? different job? ...)

Log entry: 2024-11-27T12:46:31.2507143Z D:\a\1\s>  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli sql db export --admin-password *** --admin-user sqladmin --storage-key $(storageAccountKeyDbaseBk) --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://s.blob.core.windows.net/frontendbk/SQLBK20241127124631.bacpac --name sqldb-frontend-prod --resource-group RG-ONYX-PROD --server sql-onyx-prod

Thats the issue, when I passed in the --storage-key $env:STORAGEACCOUNTKEYDBASEBK:  It treated it like a Literal and only grabbed the Litteral.      I'm trying to figure out how the get the Value from the Pipeline varable into the PS script in yaml.

@JoeRicklefs you might have a typo or maybe you are not referencing the variable in the right place. You need to clarify where that variable is coming from, i.e. where it's defined or retrieved (same job? different job? ...). Try adding a reference to the variable group in the job where you're running the task.

As in the initial post, the variable is defined in a variable group and linked to keyvault.  The Variable group is referenced in the variable section of the yaml.

@JoeRicklefs yes I've read that. But what I'm asking is WHERE are you referencing that variable, i.e. what is the scope of the variable group - is it referenced at the pipeline level? Stage? Job? That makes all the difference.

I updated the original post to show where it is referenced at the pipeline level

@JoeRicklefs added more details to my answer.

@JoeRicklefs check EDIT 2.

I switched to the Keyvault task and I can retrieve the values but still getting an issue on escaping the characters.  I tried all the suggestions from before about the single double quotes and even the $env:VariableName, but all have same result.  It has something to do with it being a secret but can't quite crack the code.  Posted new code in Edit 2

@JoeRicklefs the only difference in using a secret pipeline variable is that its value will be masked with ***** in the pipeline logs. Everything else should work just like a regular pipeline variable. I honestly don't know what else to do to help you. As a last try, copy my sample pipeline and do just enough changes to get the value from your variable group or use a keyvault task and check if the text file artifact is being published with the right value. Issue might be in Azure CLI (but I doubt it).
